# CardView.java error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'"

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview

**FINAL EDIT**
This whole issue turned out to be a big red herring.  Yes, Android Studio did give me these problems as if they were real, but once I properly fixed all the other errors in my code base, synced the Gradle, made the project, and had a working Emulator to properly run the code on, they went away.  Basically, if this error is here, it isn't a real error, it just means the rest of your code hasn't had a successful build since you last updated your "implementation" section of the gradle.

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm upgrading a 6-year old internal-use-only Android project to be compatible with modern devices, trying to make sure everything is using up-to-date Android libraries.  I've gotten every error and most every warning ironed out except one.

When upgrading from the old CardView to androidx.cardview, the new CardView.java now has 20 instances of the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'".  One of its import statements is "import androidx.cardview.R", which the Android docs says doesn't even exist.  And in case it's not clear, the file is read-only since it's an import of the widget library.

I have tried resyncing the gradle, rebuilding the project, invalidating the cache and restarting, all the typical "have you turned it off and back on" options.  I am running the latest version of Android Studio (2021.1.1 patch 1), have the classpath pointing at the latest gradle (`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'`) and am implementing what I believe are the latest androidx libraries:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
```

These errors are making it so I cannot compile and test the app.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Apparently the errors mentioned were not what was causing the app to compile.  I had a different, unlisted problem in a different file that did not appear until I opened each file one by one.  The CardView error is still there, just not preventing program execution.

EDIT 2: Image for context.[image]

Comment: If you share your full error stack trace maybe I can help better!

Comment: So I just edited my original post, but the error listed isn't actually preventing compilation.  Turns out something else was.  I'll see if I can attach a screen grab of what is showing in my IDE, but the error is literally with a readonly library file.